# Is there a better way to write this? Checking scenarios

Tags: java, optimization, if-statement

So I have this code that checks 4 parameters (author, title, keyword and subject) to do some dynamic sql query generation for a project I'm working on and I was just wondering if anyone knew of a better way to write this out. I get the feeling this is a really inefficient way to do this but it's late and I'm tired. Please let me know if you know of any better way to do this, it's just a bunch of if/else case checking statements at this point.

Thanks!

```
if(_author!=null)
                {
                    query += authorQ;
                    if(_title != null)
                    {
                        if(conjunct[0] == 0)
                        {
                            query += " AND ";
                            query += titleQ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            query += " OR ";
                            query += titleQ;
                        }
                        if(_keyword != null)
                        {
                            if(conjunct[1] == 0)
                            {
                                query += " AND ";
                                query += keywordQ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                query += " OR ";
                                query += keywordQ;
                            }
                            if(_subject != null)
                            {
                                if(conjunct[2] == 0)
                                {
                                    query += " AND ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    query += " OR ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                            }                               
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(_subject != null)
                            {
                                if(conjunct[2] == 0)
                                {
                                    query += " AND ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    query += " OR ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                            }                       
                        }
                    }//title = null
                    else
                    {
                        if(_keyword != null)
                        {
                            if(conjunct[1] == 0)
                            {
                                query += " AND ";
                                query += keywordQ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                query += " OR ";
                                query += keywordQ;
                            }
                            if(_subject != null)
                            {
                                if(conjunct[2] == 0)
                                {
                                    query += " AND ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    query += " OR ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                            }                               
                        }
                        else //keyword null
                        {
                            if(_subject != null)
                            {
                                if(conjunct[2] == 0)
                                {
                                    query += " AND ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    query += " OR ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                            }
                            //if subject's null at this point we don't care
                        }
                    }
                }
                else //author null
                {
                    if(_title != null)
                    {
                        if(conjunct[0] == 0)
                        {
                            query += " AND ";
                            query += titleQ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            query += " OR ";
                            query += titleQ;
                        }
                        if(_keyword != null)
                        {
                            if(conjunct[1] == 0)
                            {
                                query += " AND ";
                                query += keywordQ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                query += " OR ";
                                query += keywordQ;
                            }
                            if(_subject != null)
                            {
                                if(conjunct[2] == 0)
                                {
                                    query += " AND ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    query += " OR ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                            }                               
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(_subject != null)
                            {
                                if(conjunct[2] == 0)
                                {
                                    query += " AND ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    query += " OR ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                            }                       
                        }
                    }//title = null
                    else
                    {
                        if(_keyword != null)
                        {
                            if(conjunct[1] == 0)
                            {
                                query += " AND ";
                                query += keywordQ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                query += " OR ";
                                query += keywordQ;
                            }
                            if(_subject != null)
                            {
                                if(conjunct[2] == 0)
                                {
                                    query += " AND ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    query += " OR ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                            }                               
                        }
                        else //keyword null
                        {
                            if(_subject != null)
                            {
                                if(conjunct[2] == 0)
                                {
                                    query += " AND ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    query += " OR ";
                                    query += subjectQ;
                                }
                            }
                            //if subject's null at this point we don't care
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You can take the query+=variableName; out of the if-statement and you can use ternary opertor:  eg:-
 query += (conjunct[0] == 0 ? " AND " : " OR ");
 query+=titleQ;

Comment: I know a really great way, `but it's late and I'm tired` ;)

Comment: Also, a lot of that code is "dead" i.e. unreachable, just drop it into a recent version of eclipse with all warnings enabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a more structured and scalable approach, see example below. By the way, you shouldn't really be putting user input straight into SQL queries - use prepared statements instead to try to guard against injection attacks.

```
// test values
String _author = "authorfoo";
String _title = "titlebar";
String _keyword = null;
String _subject = "subjectfoo";
String authorQ = "author=" + _author;
String subjectQ = "subject=" + _subject;
String titleQ = "title="+ _title;
String keywordQ = "keyword=" + _keyword;
int conjunct[] = new int[]{ 0, 1, 1, 0};

// query building code
String []inputs = {_author, _title, _keyword, _subject};
String []queries = {authorQ, titleQ, keywordQ, subjectQ};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0 ; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i] != null) {
        if (builder.length() > 0) { // don't start query with connective
            if (conjunct[i] == 0) {
                builder.append(" AND ");
            } else {
                builder.append(" OR ");
            }
        }
        builder.append(queries[i]);
    }
}
String query = builder.toString();
System.out.println(query);
```

Comment: wow that is much better. i definitely should not write code past midnight. also, as for sql injection the project specifies that we don't have to worry about it for the class hence the direct user input. thanks or your help, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = _author ? authorQ  : 1;
t = _title ? titleQ  : 1;
k = _keyword ? keywordQ  : 1;
s = _subject ? subjectQ  : 1;

c1 = conjunct[0] ? " OR " : " AND ";
c2 = conjunct[1] ? " OR " : " AND ";
c3 = conjunct[2] ? " OR " : " AND ";

query += a + c1 + t + c2 + k + c3 + s;
```

Comment: So for _author == null and conunction[0] != 0 query becomes ... 1 OR .... What does that sql query evaluate to?